# Cubos OLAP - error de Localhost no se está ejecutando en modo multidimensional -

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Yo no he hecho la base, la descargué especial para *datawarehouse*, se llama: ***AdventureWorksDW2016_EXT.bak***.
La cual importé a SQL Server Data enginer, mi versión con `select @@version`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dice:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017
>   17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 16299: )

Utilizo **Visual Studio** 2015 con la herramienta: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de importar la base de datos tuve que hacer **Database Diagrams** pero no me fué fácil pues decía un error de que la base no existía, entonces buscando entré aquí:
 *AdventureWorksDW2016_EXT\Properties\Files*
 . Aquí agregué a [sa] para el **Owner**

Seguí las prácticas hasta llegar a visual studio. En las bases de datos solo aparecen estas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hago es archivo-nuevo-proyecto-bussiness intelligence-Analysis services-proyecto multidimensional y minería de datos- dar  nombre y siguiente.

De ahí a *nuevo origen de datos* y tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto tuve que ir a *Servicios - Servicio de Sql Browser - propiedades - inicio automático - aplicar - reiniciar* para que me reconociera el servidor.
Luego `(Según el pdf que sigo para el ejemplo cuyo año es del 2008)` inicio con - utilizar una cuenta de servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar en siguiente me trae la cadena de conexión que es esta:

> Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=DESKTOP-U0TO9VE;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2016_EXT

Creo mi nueva vista de origen de datos, todo normal, ahora hago el cubo con nuevo cubo, etc.

Llego a la parte de procesado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me trae los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visitado foros en inglés, hasta las preguntas sobre este mismo tema en StackOverflow inglés y las soluciones no están bien detalladas, hay configuraciones que no logro encontrar, o sus soluciones a mi no me funcionaron. Una solución fue dar mi servidor en la implementación la cual ya hice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero sigue sin funcionar. Ya di permisos, ya hice lo que he encontrado y no me funciona.

Dejaré esto aquí y seguiré buscando, sé que hay o habrá más con este problema.

Edito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ver si te ayuda esto. Es sobre todo para que mires si está en modo multidimensional. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Analysis+Services+(SSAS)/147503/

Comment: encontraste la solucion? por que tengo el mismo problema

Comment: me interesa la solucion, estoy sobre el mismo tema..

Comment: @moneyBox la solución que me funcionó fue quitando el sql a una versión anterior

Comment: @JoseLuis gracias por el dato...

Comment: @JaimeGarcíaPérez solo para dejar constancia, a mí si me funcionó lo que está en el enlace que compartió.

Comment: Tambien me funciono el link que compartio Jaime

Answer (score 0):

por si le sirve a alguien
el servidor está en otro modo que no es multidimensional
hay que desinstalar SQL server, volver a crear la instancia y seleccionar la opción de multidimensional [image: opcion]